# Adding Android SDK platform-tools to PATH downloaded from umake

Tags: command-line, android, android-studio, android-sdk

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr, and I downloaded Android Studio with the `umake` tool provided by Ubuntu. This downloaded Android Studio at `/root/tools/android/android-studio`,
and platform-tools and all other tools at `/root/Android/Sdk/`.

Android Studio on my PC is working just fine, and I am able to create an application and also run it on my mobile phone using it. But I want command line access to the tools and so I want to add them to the environment path.

To add them to environment path, I did this:

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

And added the following lines-

```
 export PATH=${PATH}:/root/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
 export PATH=${PATH}:/root/Android/Sdk/build-tools
```

**But this dosen't work. When I give the command `adb` from a terminal, it dosen't seem to invoke the adb tools from the platform-tools folder. Instead it tells me to install android-tools-adb.**

I am however being able to `cd` into platform-tools, and run `adb` and other tools from there, but I don't want to do that again and again. Also, how can I add Android Studio to my `PATH` so that I don't have to `cd` into its bin/ directory again and again?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What say `which adb` and `which -a adb`?

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME"/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
```

Answer (score 8):

If you install Android SDK through Android Studio (or any other way that put you Android SDK folder under this path), execute this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME"/Android/Sdk/platform-tools"
```

Answer (score 2):

I added this line to the bottom of my .bashrc and it works.

```
export PATH=/home/[myusername]/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH

source ~/.bashrc  #To update the bashrc with the changes in the current tab
```

I don't understand the `PATH=${PATH}` syntax in your example, so I can't comment on whether it's correct or not, but you could try the syntax I used.

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:[path to add]` means that the path will be appended at the end to the original Path-variable. You used `PATH=[path to add]:$PATH`, what means that the path will be appended before the Path-variable.

Answer (score 2):

I installed Android Studio via snap. So I had to add the platform-tools folder path to the .bashrc file.

1. If you use visual studio code as editor type this in the terminal

   code ~/.bashrc
2. It will open the visual studio code and the .bashrc file is opened in it. Go to the bottom of the file and add the following export,

```
    # Android Path
    if [ -d "$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools" ] ; then
     export PATH="$HOME/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"
    fi
```

Note: Leave and empty line at the end of .bashrc file. So the shell program knows it is the end of file (EOF).

Saved the .bashrc file and quit visual studio code

Go to Terminal and source the updated .bashrc file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 common ways to set your `PATH` environment variable in `~/.bashrc`. We may mess them up (I did).

- Method 1: `export PATH="~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH"`
- Method 2: `PATH=~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:$PATH`

The `export` method requires to put the `PATH` value between quotes and the second does not.

I recommend the second method - set the `PATH` variable directly - because we may not have to worried about quote(s).